# Change toc_depth field in bookdown pdf output

Tags: bookdown

I am creating a book in PDF with `bookdown`, and I would like to change the number of the `toc_depth` field when converting the book to PDF. This is my `_output-yml`:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
  config:
    toc:
      before: |
        <li><a href="./">A Minimal Book Example</a></li>
      after: |
        <li><a href="https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown" target="blank">Published with bookdown</a></li>
      toc_depth: 5
    download: ["pdf", "epub"]
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: yes
bookdown::epub_book: default
```

I added `toc_depth: 5` with no results. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you have `toc_depth` within the `bookdown::gitbook` block, which is responsible for HTML output. If you want this for PDF output, as your title suggests, you need to add it there, i.e.

```
...
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: yes
  toc_depth: 5
...
```

Se also: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html